# Arduino rc plane logger

Tags: sd-card, accelerometer, gyroscope, 101

Well, I want to make an rc plane with an arduino that logs to an sd card 

A) Video

B) Accelerometer data

C) Tempature

D) Humitity

E) Atmospheric pressure

F) Gyroscope Data

What arduino/parts should I use? I have a maximum of 170 grams or 6 OZ. 
The arduino will not control the plane, just log data. I'm thinking an arduino 101... but I would like to know if there is a lighter/better way. 
 THANKS! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "shopping" question.

Comment: OH, sorry. I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an Arduino answer but a Raspberry Pi with a Sense hat will record most of what you need with little coding.  Add a Pi camera and you have all this for about $100.  The Sense Hat temperature sensor doesn't work because it is too close to the CPU but you could get a digital thermometer for a few bucks.

Comment: This is VERY false. You don't need to learn Python. You can easily make a Pi and Pi Cam work with C++, a much more powerful language. WiringPi also has many functions such as `pinMode()` and `digitalWrite()`... Sounds familiar.

Comment: Thanks for the corretion @Dat Ha.  I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I've completed a similar project.

- For the Arduino, I used a Pro Mini for its small size and weight.
- For the accel/gyro, I used an MPU-6050. 2 bird, 1 stone!
- For the Temp/Baro, I used an MPL3115A2. Again, 2 bird, 1 stone!
- [For the camera feed, use one of these pre-built things.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/200W-HD-Camera-Shoot-Module-For-Hubsan-X4-H107C-A34-Mini-Aircraft-Quadcopter-/141434404852?hash=item20ee25bff4:g:q5IAAOSwajVUN5Ir)